# How do I fix an error in my script that revolves around an SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, discord

Could you please help me resolve a problem within my script?
I have this function for which I have the command !set-stats. When I execute it with an already created character within an other function and finish the !set-stats command it shows me this error:

```
ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command set-stats
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\daris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\DariProjectsPython\discordbot3\main7.py", line 567, in set_stats
    c.execute(f'UPDATE characters SET {set_placeholders} WHERE user_id=? AND name=?', (*answers.values(), user_id, 
character_name,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Ninjutsu Mastery

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\daris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "c:\Users\daris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\daris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OperationalError: no such column: Ninjutsu Mastery
```

I searched through the database and had a column on both the database and the limitations. Please help!

```
@bot.command(name='set-stats')
async def set_stats(ctx, character_name):
    user_id = ctx.author.id

    # Check if the user has a character with the specified name
    with sqlite3.connect('characters.db') as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute('SELECT * FROM characters WHERE user_id=? AND name=?', (user_id, character_name))
        existing_character = c.fetchone()

        if not existing_character:
            await ctx.send(f"You don't have a character named {character_name}.")
            return

        # Check if character stats are already set
        if existing_character[13] is not None:  # Assuming health is the first stat in your database
            await ctx.send("Stats for this character have already been set.")
            return

        # Define base values based on character ranks
        base_values = {
    "Genin": {
        "Chakra": 80,
        "Health": 155,
        "Stamina": 5,
        "Strength": 5,
        "Ninjutsu Mastery": 33,
        "Genjutsu Mastery": 55,
        "Taijutsu Mastery": 27,
        "Kekei Genkai Mastery": 33,
        "Senjutsu Mastery": 55,
        "Kenjutsu Mastery": 18,
        "Chakra Control": 15,
        "Intelligence": 5,
        "Speed": 5
    },
    "Chunin": {
        "Chakra": 150,
        "Health": 172,
        "Stamina": 6,
        "Strength": 10,
        "Ninjutsu Mastery": 45,
        "Genjutsu Mastery": 60,
        "Taijutsu Mastery": 32,
        "Kekei Genkai Mastery": 45,
        "Senjutsu Mastery": 60,
        "Kenjutsu Mastery": 20,
        "Chakra Control": 50,
        "Intelligence": 6,
        "Speed": 6
    },
    "Jonin": {
        "Chakra": 250,
        "Health": 190,
        "Stamina": 6,
        "Strength": 20,
        "Ninjutsu Mastery": 70,
        "Genjutsu Mastery": 70,
        "Taijutsu Mastery": 35,
        "Kekei Genkai Mastery": 70,
        "Senjutsu Mastery": 70,
        "Kenjutsu Mastery": 25,
        "Chakra Control": 100,
        "Intelligence": 6,
        "Speed": 6
    },
    "Special Jonin": {
        "Chakra": 270,
        "Health": 191,
        "Stamina": 7,
        "Strength": 20,
        "Ninjutsu Mastery": 75,
        "Genjutsu Mastery": 70,
        "Taijutsu Mastery": 35,
        "Kekei Genkai Mastery": 75,
        "Senjutsu Mastery": 70,
        "Kenjutsu Mastery": 27,
        "Chakra Control": 120,
        "Intelligence": 7,
        "Speed": 7
    },
    "Anbu": {
        "Chakra": 350,
        "Health": 210,
        "Stamina": 7,
        "Strength": 20,
        "Ninjutsu Mastery": 90,
        "Genjutsu Mastery": 120,
        "Taijutsu Mastery": 40,
        "Kekei Genkai Mastery": 90,
        "Senjutsu Mastery": 120,
        "Kenjutsu Mastery": 30,
        "Chakra Control": 200,
        "Intelligence": 7,
        "Speed": 7
    },
    "Special Anbu": {
        "Chakra": 400,
        "Health": 223,
        "Stamina": 7,
        "Strength": 20,
        "Ninjutsu Mastery": 95,
        "Genjutsu Mastery": 120,
        "Taijutsu Mastery": 50,
        "Kekei Genkai Mastery": 95,
        "Senjutsu Mastery": 120,
        "Kenjutsu Mastery": 30,
        "Chakra Control": 350,
        "Intelligence": 7,
        "Speed": 8
    },
    "Co-Kage": {
        "Chakra": 450,
        "Health": 240,
        "Stamina": 8,
        "Strength": 35,
        "Ninjutsu Mastery": 110,
        "Genjutsu Mastery": 125,
        "Taijutsu Mastery": 60,
        "Kekei Genkai Mastery": 110,
        "Senjutsu Mastery": 125,
        "Kenjutsu Mastery": 35,
        "Chakra Control": 450,
        "Intelligence": 8,
        "Speed": 9
    },
    "Kage": {
        "Chakra": 500,
        "Health": 253,
        "Stamina": 8,
        "Strength": 35,
        "Ninjutsu Mastery": 125,
        "Genjutsu Mastery": 150,
        "Taijutsu Mastery": 80,
        "Kekei Genkai Mastery": 125,
        "Senjutsu Mastery": 150,
        "Kenjutsu Mastery": 45,
        "Chakra Control": 500,
        "Intelligence": 8,
        "Speed": 10
    },
}

        remaining_points = 25
        answers = {}

        for stat_name, stat_value in base_values[existing_character[7]].items():
            await ctx.send(f"{stat_name.capitalize()}: {stat_value} (Remaining Points: {remaining_points})")

            response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author)
            answer = response.content

            if not answer.isdigit():
                await ctx.send("Please enter a valid number.")
                return

            answer = int(answer)

            if answer < 0 or answer > remaining_points:
                await ctx.send(f"Please enter a number between 0 and {remaining_points}.")
                return

            remaining_points -= answer
            answers[stat_name] = answer

        # Update the database with the provided stats
    set_placeholders = ', '.join(f'`{key}` = ?' for key in answers.keys())
    c.execute(f'UPDATE characters SET {set_placeholders} WHERE user_id=? AND name=?', (*answers.values(), user_id, character_name))

    await ctx.send(f"Stats for {character_name} have been successfully set.")
```

```
@bot.command(name='create-character')
async def create_character(ctx):
    user_id = ctx.author.id

    # Get the maximum character number for the user
    c.execute('SELECT MAX(character_number) FROM characters WHERE user_id=?', (user_id,))
    max_character_number = c.fetchone()[0]

    # Set character_number to 1 if the user has no existing characters
    character_number = 1 if max_character_number is None else max_character_number + 1

    questions = ["Name of the character:",
                 "Age of the character:",
                 "Clan:",
                 "Village:",
                 "Rank:",
                 "Chakra Type:",
                 "Kekei Genkai (Type 'None' if not applicable):",
                 "Dodjutsu (Type 'None' if not applicable):",
                 "Fighting style:",
                 "Backstory:"]

    answers = []

    i = 0  # Initialize loop variable outside the loop

    while i < len(questions):
        await ctx.send(questions[i])

        response = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author)
        answer = response.content

        if i == 2:  # For the "Clan" field
            # Check if the provided clan is valid
            valid_clans = ["Uchiha Clan", "Senju Clan", "Hyuga Clan", "Nara Clan", "Yamanaka Clan", "Akimichi Clan", "Aburame Clan", "Inuzuka Clan", "Sarutobi Clan", "Hatake Clan", "Kaguya Clan", "Uzumaki Clan", "Kazekage Clan", "Hozuki Clan", "Terumi Clan", "Kurosuki Clan", "Kurama Clan", "Fuma Clan", "Uzumaki Clan", "Jugo's Clan", "Jinchuriki Clans"]
            if answer not in valid_clans:
                await ctx.send(f"Invalid clan. Please choose from: {', '.join(valid_clans)}")
                continue  # Stay on the same question

        if i == 3:  # For the "Village" field
            # Check if the provided village is valid
            valid_villages = ["Konohagakure", "Sunagakure", "Kirigakure", "Otokagure"]
            if answer not in valid_villages:
                await ctx.send(f"Invalid village. Please choose from: {', '.join(valid_villages)}")
                continue  # Stay on the same question

        if i == 4:  # For the "Rank" field
            # Check if the provided rank is valid
            valid_ranks = ["Genin", "Chunin", "Jonin", "Special Jonin", "Anbu", "Special Anbu", "Co-Kage", "Kage"]
            if answer not in valid_ranks:
                await ctx.send(f"Invalid rank. Please choose from: {', '.join(valid_ranks)}")
                continue  # Stay on the same question

        if i == 5:  # For the "Chakra Type" field
            # Check if the provided chakra type is valid
            valid_chakra_types = ["Earth", "Fire", "Wind", "Water", "Lightning", "Yin", "Yang"]
            if answer not in valid_chakra_types:
                await ctx.send(f"Invalid chakra type. Please choose from: {', '.join(valid_chakra_types)}")
                continue  # Stay on the same question

        if i == 6:  # For the "KekeiGenkai" field
            # Check if the provided kekkei genkai is valid
            valid_kekkei_genkai = [
                "Ice Release (Haku's Kekkei Genkai)",
                "Lava Release",
                "Storm Release",
                "Boil Release",
                "Magnet Release",
                "Scorch Release",
                "Explosion Release",
                "Dust Release",
                "Crystal Release",
                "Swift Release",
                "Steel Release",
                "Typhoon Release",
                "Wood Release (excluding Sage Art Wood Release: True Several Thousand Hands)",
                "Blaze Release",
                "Jūgo's Kekkei Genkai (Cursed Seal of Heaven)",
                "Shikotsumyaku (Kimimaro's Kekkei Genkai)",
                "Ice-Mirror Clone Technique (Haku's unique ice technique)",
                "Storm Style Kekkei Genkai (Darui's unique lightning and water combination)",
                "Explosion Release (Deidara's Kekkei Genkai)",
                "Crystal Release (Guren's unique crystal techniques)",
                "Swift Release (Fourth Raikage's Kekkei Genkai)",
                "Dust Release (Mū's Kekkei Tōta)",
                "Ice Release (Mei Terumī's unique ice techniques)",
                "Particle Style (Mū's Kekkei Tōta)",
                "Storm Release (Third Raikage's unique lightning and water combination)",
                "None"  
            ]
            if answer not in valid_kekkei_genkai:
                await ctx.send(f"Invalid kekkei genkai. Please choose from: {', '.join(valid_kekkei_genkai)}")
                continue  # Stay on the same question

        if i == 7:  # For the "Dodjutsu" field
            # Check if the provided dodjutsu is valid
            valid_dodjutsu = ["Sharingan", "Byakugan", "Rinnegan", "Mangekyō Sharingan", "None"]
            if answer not in valid_dodjutsu:
                await ctx.send(f"Invalid dodjutsu. Please choose from: {', '.join(valid_dodjutsu)}")
                continue  # Stay on the same question

        if i == 8:  # For the "Fighting Style" field
            # Check if the provided fighting style is valid
            valid_fighting_styles = ["Taijutsu", "Ninjutsu", "Genjutsu", "Jutsu", "Senjutsu", "Fuinjutsu", "Chakra Flow", "Kekei Genkai", "Kenjutsu", "Sage Mode", "Shuriken Jutsu", "Kinjutsu", "Cooperation Ninjutsu", "Juinjutsu", "Jujutsu", "Nintaijutsu", "Regeneration Techniques", "Reincarnation Ninjutsu", "None"]
            if answer not in valid_fighting_styles:
                await ctx.send(f"Invalid fighting style. Please choose from: {', '.join(valid_fighting_styles)}")
                continue  # Stay on the same question

        answers.append(answer)
        i += 1  # Increment loop variable only if the input is valid

    # Insert the character into the database
    c.execute('''
              INSERT INTO characters (user_id, character_number, name, age, clan, village, rank, chakra_type, kekei_genkai, dodjutsu, fighting_style, backstory)
              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
              ''', (user_id, character_number) + tuple(answers[:12]))  # Use only the first 12 answers
    conn.commit()

    await ctx.send("Character created successfully!")

@bot.command(name='edit-character')
async def edit_character(ctx, character_name, field, *new_value):
    user_id = ctx.author.id

    # Check if the user has a character
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM characters WHERE user_id=? AND name=?', (user_id, character_name))
    existing_character = c.fetchone()

    if not existing_character:
        await ctx.send(f"You don't have a character named {character_name}. Use !create-character to create one.")
        return

    # Get the character_number for the specified character
    character_number = existing_character[2]

    field = field.lower()
    valid_fields = [
        "name", "age", "clan", "village", "rank", "chakra_type",
        "kekei_genkai", "dodjutsu", "fighting_style", "backstory"
    ]

    if field not in valid_fields:
        await ctx.send(f"Invalid field. Valid fields: {', '.join(valid_fields)}")
        return

    new_value = ' '.join(new_value)

    # Update the character field in the database
    c.execute(f'UPDATE characters SET {field}=? WHERE user_id=? AND character_number=?', (new_value, user_id, character_number))
    conn.commit()

    await ctx.send(f"{field.capitalize()} updated successfully for {character_name}!")

    # Assign roles based on the edited field
    await assign_roles(ctx, field, new_value)

async def assign_roles(ctx, field, new_value):
    member = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild

    # Define role IDs for each field
    role_mapping = {
        "rank": {"Chunin": 1205947143177633903, "Jonin": 1234567891, "Kage": 1234567892},  # Replace with your actual role IDs
        "clan": {"Uchiha Clan": 1234567893, "Hyuga Clan": 1234567894},  IDs
        
    }

    field = field.lower()
    if field in role_mapping:
        role_id = role_mapping[field].get(new_value)
        if role_id:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
            if role:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                await ctx.send(f"Role {role.name} assigned successfully!")


async def assign_roles(ctx, field, new_value):
    member = ctx.author
    guild = ctx.guild

    # Define role IDs for each field
    role_mapping = {
        "rank": {"Genin": 1205947143177633903, "Chunin": 1234567891, "Jonin": 1234567892}, 
        "clan": {"Uchiha Clan": 1234567893, "Hyuga Clan": 1234567894}, I
        
    }

    field = field.lower()
    if field in role_mapping:
        # Remove previous rank role
        previous_rank = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_mapping["rank"].get("Genin"))  # Assuming "Genin" is the default rank
        if previous_rank:
            await member.remove_roles(previous_rank)

        # Add new rank role
        role_id = role_mapping[field].get(new_value)
        if role_id:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, id=role_id)
            if role:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                await ctx.send(f"Role {role.name} assigned successfully!")
```

Table

```
c.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS characters (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        user_id INTEGER,
        character_number INTEGER,
        name TEXT,
        age TEXT,
        clan TEXT,
        village TEXT,
        rank TEXT,
        chakra_type TEXT,
        kekei_genkai TEXT,
        dodjutsu TEXT,
        fighting_style TEXT,
        backstory TEXT,
        health INTEGER,
        chakra INTEGER,
        stamina INTEGER,
        strength INTEGER,
        ninjutsu_mastery INTEGER,
        genjutsu_mastery INTEGER,
        taijutsu_mastery INTEGER,
        kekei_genkai_mastery INTEGER,
        senjutsu_mastery INTEGER,
        kenjutsu_mastery INTEGER,
        chakra_control INTEGER,
        intelligence INTEGER,  
        speed INTEGER,         
        UNIQUE(user_id, character_number)
    )
''')
```

I checked on the database and searched through the net and yet I'm still struggling!

Comment: Which query is getting that error? Please post the full traceback of the error. Put it in a code block rather than quotation so the formatting will be perserved.

Comment: @Barmar im sorry im still new to this.I have only one database wich is used by the command !create-character and the set-stats if youre asking for this.

Comment: If the solution would be helpful to others, post it as an answer below. Otherwise, you should delete the question.